# How to send the cursor from a mongo db find query as a result in flask

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, cursor

I want to be able to query my mongo db and get the results for all entries in my `stocksCollection` collection. I am using `allStocks = list(stocksCollection.find({}))` which gives me a list of all the entries in that collection. However, when I try to return this as the response to a get request, I get the error:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. 
The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
```

Here is the simple code I used to get this:

```
@app.route("/stocks", methods=['GET'])
def getAllStocks():
    return list(stocksCollection.find({}))
```

I have also tried: `return stocksCollection.find({})` (errors because it is a type: cursor) and

```
allStocks = list(stocksCollection.find({}))
return {'data': allStocks}
```

But that just gives me the error `TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable`. Any ideas on what formatt I can change this cursor to so that I am able to return it to my api call (this will not be serving up directly to a webpage, just being called by the frontend to do some calculations)

Answer (score 1):

**Create a JSONEncoder class to make ObjectId JSON serializable**

```
import json
from bson import ObjectId

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

**And then use JSONEncoder class as below (in json.dumps) and make the *_id* value JSON serializable and append the data into a new list return it.**

```
@app.route("/stocks", methods=['GET'])
def getAllStocks():
    output = []
    all_data = stocksCollection.find({})
    for data in all_data:
        data['_id'] = json.dumps(data['_id'], cls=JSONEncoder)
        output.appned(data)
    return {"data": output}
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, then flask just gives me this error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.`

Comment: You cannot return a list as an api response. getAllStocks() is updated. Now this will work.

Comment: Nope then I just get the error: `unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: misspelled *.append* on output variable inside for loop.